# neo4j-ogm 2.0 configuration error driver null

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-ogm

i have set my neo4j ,but it get deriver error

```
Configuration cfg = Components.configuration();
    cfg.driverConfiguration()
        .setDriverClassName("org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.http.driver.HttpDriver")
        .setURI("http://localhost:7474")
        .setCredentials("neo4j","neo4j");
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = new SessionFactory(cfg,"rdf2rdf.domain");
    //Session session = Neo4jSessionFactory.getInstance().getNeo4jSession();
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
```

but it get an error!!!

```
Exception in thread "main" org.neo4j.ogm.exception.ServiceNotFoundException: Driver: null
at org.neo4j.ogm.service.DriverService.load(DriverService.java:51)
at org.neo4j.ogm.service.DriverService.load(DriverService.java:63)
at org.neo4j.ogm.service.Components.loadDriver(Components.java:126)
at org.neo4j.ogm.service.Components.driver(Components.java:84)
at org.neo4j.ogm.session.SessionFactory.openSession(SessionFactory.java:79)
at rdf2rule.rdf2rule.App.main(App.java:48)
```

it seems my sessionfacotry is wrong! can anyone help me? please.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to [include the http driver](http://neo4j.com/docs/ogm/java/stable/#_dependencies_for_the_neo4j_ogm):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j-ogm-http-driver</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Also, please change
`Configuration cfg = Components.configuration();`

to

`Configuration cfg = new Configuration();`

Comment: thanks!  it works. but i still want to know the differences between  Components.configuration() and  Configuration()

Comment: The ogm docs are incorrect. When setting up a new configuration you always need to instantiate a new one instead of reusing. We will be removing the other method in the next release